# Given we are up again time now on this

Tags: british-english

Can someone split the bold part of this sentence into parts, please?

> **Given we are up again time now on this**, are the bugs listed in
> priority order for fixing?

Like this:

> Given + we are up again + ... + on this

I got the meaning, thanks to Google Translate, it's a valid sentence, but I can't manage to identify all its components.

Comment: *again* is probably a typo for *against* (possibly an auto-correct typo)

Comment: The sentence with the typo does not make sense, and I don't think Google Translate quite conveys the intended meaning (although the second half of the sentence is the important part, and the typo doesn't affect that).

Comment: Given **that** we are up again**st** time [now] on this, ...

Comment: Actually, it's the idiomatic use of *given* by itself that may be the surprise.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - What's 'idiomatic' about the use of 'given'? Given that the ship has a big hole in the side, do we still want to go aboard?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It should have been 'against'. It's so clear to me now. =) Thank you.
Strangely, not only did Google Translate fail, but even Grammarly wasn't able to detect that typo.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I read *given* as a very shortened version of "Considering that we might be given," "If we take it as given," "Let's assume it's given," or "Given the fact that."